# Cannot find symbol variable for Custom Icon

Tags: android, android-activity

I am configurating custom icons for my app main menu, using Droidicon (https://github.com/theDazzler/droidicon/wiki/How-to-Use)
Everything goes well until I build the project and I get the following message:

> Error:(250, 48) error: cannot find symbol variable customBottomLeft

This is the code relating to that icon:

```
View customBottomLeft=findViewById(R.id.customBottomLeft);
        if (SDK_INT < JELLY_BEAN) {
            customBottomLeft.setBackgroundDrawable(customBottomLeftIcon);
        } else {
            customBottomLeft.setBackground(customBottomLeftIcon);
        }

        //Bottom Right
        Map<String, Integer> customMapCOntacto = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        customMapCOntacto.put("custom-bottom-right", 0xe600);

        CustomTypefaceHolder customTypefaceHolder4 = new CustomTypefaceHolder("custom", R.raw.contacto, customMapCOntacto);
        TypefaceManager.getInstance().addNewTypefaceHolder(customTypefaceHolder4);

        IconicFontDrawable customBottomRightIcon = new IconicFontDrawable(this.getApplicationContext());
        customBottomRightIcon.setIcon("custom-bottom-right");
        customBottomRightIcon.setIconColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary));
        customBottomRightIcon.setIconPadding(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin_10));
        customBottomRightIcon.setIntrinsicWidth(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.db_main_icon));
        customBottomRightIcon.setIntrinsicHeight(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.db_main_icon));
```

I have checked and tested a few other suggestions from other questions and answers on stackoverflow, without success.

Here is my XML file:

```
 <View
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="1px"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_5"
                                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_5"
                                android:background="@color/divider" />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/pager_height_half"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                                android:id="@+id/am_iv_about_us" >
                                <View
                                    android:id="@+id/customBottomLeft"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    >

                                </View>
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

```
View customBottomLeft=findViewById(R.id.customBottomLeft);
```

make sure you have view with id **customBottomLeft** in your xml

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited my original post with the XML file.  customBottomLeft does appear. Am I missing something?

Comment: are you calling findViewById within your activity class?

Comment: Yes, it appears. I have 4 icons and they all give me the following error. Do I need to create four different folders in my files with the custom icons name? Error:(250, 48) error: cannot find symbol variable customBottomLeft
Error:(271, 49) error: cannot find symbol variable customBottomRight
Error:(229, 46) error: cannot find symbol variable customTopRight
Error:(208, 45) error: cannot find symbol variable customTopLeft

Comment: can you modifty question with  complete xml and code file where you are accessing icons